# Multiple percent calculations

Tags: percentages

I would like to ask trivial question about calculating percents.
Problem appeared during accounting calculations.

I've got $100$ Euro of Tax.
There was a $10\%$ ratio which I was allowed to deduct from payments.
Now there is a second pre-ratio, let's say $25\%$ which I must also calculate, ($25$ Euro) then I calculate old ratio from it. Result is $2.5$ Euro, which I can deduct.

I can write it down as $0.25 \cdot 100 \cdot 0.1 = 2.5$ and that looks pretty obvious.

What about rest of Tax which I must pay: How could I write it down using only multiplying/dividing? First thought about using $0.75 * 100 * 0.9$ is of course wrong.

I know I can get result from subtraction/addition, but what are fractions which I must use to get $97.5$ from multiplying?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 97,50 EUR proceed

100*(1-25%*10%) = 100*(1-0,25*0,10) = 100*(1-0, 025) = 100*0,975 = 97,50

If you can deduct two times (first time: 10%, second time: 25% of 10%), proceed

100*(1-10%-25%*10%) = 100*(1-0,10-0,25*0,10) = 100*(1—0,10-0, 025) = 100*(1—0,125) = 100*0,875 = 87,50

Comment: So answer is i cannot make this calculations without subtracting/adding? Problem is not about how to calculate it but why I cannot do it in similarly fractions multiplying.

Comment: Speaking more general why do I must change type of mathematical operation? It seems intuitive that such calculations can be done using same type of operation.
 In other way: how to change this equation 100(1-0,10-0,25*0,10) to get 2.5 without change subtracting into multiplying.

Comment: My misconception occurred because I taught that calculating percent twice disallows to represent it as multiplication. It doesn't change anything. In first level I am also doing subtraction unconsciously to represent it as 100*(1-0.75). Thanks Jarek!